# How to remove the space created in table overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table

Whenever I am trying to make my table scroll with overflow and display block css. Table width always getting reduced and leaves empty space. Why this is happening? What I am doing wrong here. My table is inside a div.

HTML:

```
<div id="window">
    <div id="tableContainer">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column 1</td>
                    <td>Column 2</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    display:block;

}
table 
{
width:180px;
height:100px;
display:block;
overflow:auto;
border:1px solid black;
}
table td{
    border:1px solid black;}
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KrP7v/117/

Comment: Why do you want to set the table to `display: block;`? What is wrong with the default `display: table`?

Comment: Then only am able to get scroll for table

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="window">
<div id="tableContainer">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tableContainer{
   float:left;
   height:100px;
   display:block;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   float:left   
}
  table 
{
   height:100px;
   display:block;
   float:left;
}
table td{
    border:1px solid black;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4erveak/KrP7v/118/

Here is fix for your bug but at end add a div and get them style clear:both

Comment: if you and make it bordered: #window{border:1px solid grey;float:left}

Comment: what if table width is a requirement ?

Comment: set width of div and make table 100% width

Comment: I want the table to be scrolled. not the div

Answer (score 0):

Just add
table {empty-cells: hide;}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).